# Angular2: No value accessor for a nested form

Tags: angular

I'e created a form with a nested form group:

```
this.cardForm = this.fb.group({
    number: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, this.validateCardNumber])],
    holderName: ['', Validators.required],
    expiry: this.fb.group({
      expirationMonth: ['', Validators.required],
      expirationYear: ['', Validators.required],
    }, this.validateCardExpiry),
    cvc: ['', Validators.required]
});
```

Into my template:

```
<form [formGroup]="cardForm" novalidate="novalidate" (ngSubmit)="onSave()"> 
    <div class="form-group" formGroupName="expiry">
        <label for="expirationmonth">Expiration month</label>
        <select2 id="default-select"
                name="expirationmonth"
                formControlName="expirationMonth"
                [data]="months$ | async"
                [width]="250"
                [options]="select2Options">
        </select2>
        <label for="expirationyear">Expiration year</label>
        <select2 id="default-select2"
                name="expirationyear"
                formControlName="expirationYear"
                [data]="years$ | async"
                [width]="250"
                [options]="select2Options">
        </select2>
    </div>
</form>
```

`select2` is a component from [ng2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2).

Angular is getting me this message:

> Error: No value accessor for form control with path: 'expiry -> expirationMonth'

Comment: Hi, we (at work) have been working on that topic and I gave a proper answer you may want to check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55457210/2398593 :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with forms, as per this from the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2/issues/13)

So you'd have to do some workaround for this currently. As per last comment on that issue you could try what has been done:

> *I spent sometime to figure out using with reactive form. All I had to do was implement implement ControlValueAccessor and propagate change from ngAfterViewInit on select/unselect.*

Playing around with your code, another workaround that I found was to use `ngDefaultControl` on the selects.

```
<select2 ngDefaultControl ..... ></select2>
```

But with this rises the problem, that when you make changes, it's not reflected in the form values. So a quick workaround for that would be to `patchValue` when values change. This might not be pretty, but works.

Template using the ng2-select2's change event:

```
(valueChanged)="changed($event)"
```

Component to patch one of the values:

```ts
changed(e) {   // e is of primitive type here
  this.cardForm.controls['expiry'].controls['expirationMonth'].patchValue(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ngControlDefault` to your `<div>`.

```
<div class="form-group" formGroupName="expiry" ngControlDefault>
```