# Angular: composite ControlValueAccessor to implement nested form

Tags: forms, angular

Composition of ControlValueAccessor to implement nested form is introduced in an Angular Connect 2017 presentation.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/e/2PACX-1vTS20UdnMGqA3ecrv7ww_7CDKQM8VgdH2tbHl94aXgEsYQ2cyjq62ydU3e3ZF_BaQ64kMyQa0INe2oI/pub?slide=id.g293d7d2b9d_1_1532

In this presentation, the speaker showed a way to implement custom form control which have multiple value (not only single string value but has two string field, like street and city). I want to implement it but I'm stuck. Sample app is here, does anybody know what should I correct?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2ehwx

parent component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)" novalidate>
      <label>name</label>
      <input formControlName="name">
      <app-address-form formControlName="address"></app-address-form>
      <button>submit</button>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @Input() name: string;
  submitData = '';
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      name: 'foo bar',
      address: fb.group({
        city: 'baz',
        town: 'qux',
      })
    });
  }

  onSubmit(v: any) {
    console.log(v);
  }
}
```

nested form component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-form',
  template: `
    <div [formGroup]="form">
      <label>city</label>
      <input formControlName="city" (blur)="onTouched()">
      <label>town</label>
      <input formControlName="town" (blur)="onTouched()">
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => AddressFormComponent)
    }
  ]
})
export class AddressFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  form: FormGroup;

  onTouched: () => void = () => {};

  writeValue(v: any) {
    this.form.setValue(v, { emitEvent: false });
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (v: any) => void) {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(fn);
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    disabled ? this.form.disable() : this.form.enable();
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
}
```

and error message I got

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'setValue' of undefined
at AddressFormComponent.writeValue (address-form.component.ts:32)
at setUpControl (shared.js:47)
at FormGroupDirective.addControl (form_group_directive.js:125)
at FormControlName._setUpControl (form_control_name.js:201)
at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (form_control_name.js:114)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (provider.js:249)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (view.js:472)
at checkAndUpdateNode (view.js:415)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (services.js:504)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (services.js:445)
```

I think FormGroup instance should be injected to nested form component somehow...

Comment: Can you post your code in the question?  What exact problem are you having?

Comment: @roelofs Thank you, I updated post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple issues, on your `AppComponent` change your `FormBuilder` to:

```
this.form = fb.group({
  name: 'foo bar',
  address: fb.control({ //Not using FormGroup
    city: 'baz',
    town: 'qux',
  })
});
```

On your `AddressFormComponent` you need to initialize your FormGroup like so:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    city: new FormControl,
    town: new FormControl
});
```

Here's the fork of your sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-np38bi

Comment: wow, I have to use fb.control instead of fb.group. I feel it weird because its instance is referenced as FormGroup, but It's working!! Thank you 
 @12seconds .

Comment: fmm, if FormArray is nested I got error. What is the problem? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-krhrcz

Comment: @adwd I think it is natural that custom control i a control. :) Value of custom control is just complex object.

Comment: @penleychan There is a problem with validation. If we treat nested form as FormControl then the main form is not aware of the nested form validity. Here is demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pmfq5z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts. Try to clear required fields. How can we resolve this?

Comment: @TarasHupalo, I suggest you have a look at my other answers to achieve this if you https://stackoverflow.com/a/53053333/6736888

Comment: City & Town controls are in nested form. Why should I declare it in parent. Don't we want to avoid declare these controls in multiple places?

Comment: @Manoj, a bit of different situation in this case, this was more of creating your own `ControlValueAccessor`. I would recommend another approach, the link is above your comment.

Answer (score 0):

We (at work) encountered that issue and tried different things for months: How to properly deal with nested forms.

Indeed, `ControlValueAccessor` seems to be the way to go but we found it very verbose and it was quite long to build nested forms. As we're using that pattern a lot within our app, we've ended up spending some time to investigate and try to come up with a better solution. We called it `ngx-sub-form` and it's a repo available on [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sub-form) (+ source code on [Github](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form)).

Basically, to create a sub form all you have to do is extends a class we provide and also pass your FormControls. That's it.

We've updated our codebase to use it and we're definitely happy about it so you may want to give a try and see how it goes for you :)

Everything is explained in the [README on github](https://github.com/cloudnc/ngx-sub-form).

PS: We also have a full demo running here https://cloudnc.github.io/ngx-sub-form

Comment: I'm fine with a down vote but it'd be nice to get an explanation why you think I wrote a bad answer.

Comment: Hello. Validation does not work fully in sub-components. The required mat-form-field does not get highlighted when clicking on submit. I would like to have the ability to click on submit even if the form is invalid, that way you clearly see what you missed filling the forms.
Do you have a suggestion for this problem? I tried with CVA but it does not work either.
One solution is have a ViewChild for the subcomponent, create a function so the subcomponent can call it's form markAllTouched function. But I feel this is a bit hacky.